# SQL Server Express vs SQL Server performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

Working with single user.

The duration in SQL Server Express is much much worse than SQL Server. Any idea?

Ps. same data. same machine.

Thank you

Comment: 1 - This is not an actual question.  2 - Accept answers to your questions once they are resolved, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Express will use less RAM and also is bound to I believe just 1 CPU also